# OpenGL superbible 5th edition source on Xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl, opengl-3

I downloaded the source code for the examples of the OpenGL superbible 5th edition from here:
http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/
It was a file called XCode.zip

The projects there were actually never updated for the latest Xcode for OpenGL 3.0.
I wonder if someone already walked this perilous and dark way and made these projects work, or if there is a new zip file for the latest XCode.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the examples use GLUT, which hasn't been updated to be able to use OpenGL 3 on OS X yet.

> Apple didn't update GLUT. Trying to make time to adopt GLFW as the new framework.
>
> — *Richard S. Wright Jr., [post on Twitter](http://twitter.com/opengl/status/231218659484381184)*